Nx not able to build with shared middleware lib
I'm working with NX + NestJs.
This is my app repo structure:
MyRepo
    -> apps
        -> NestJsApp1
        -> App2
    ->lib
        -> middlewares
            -> LoggerMiddleware


I have create Nestjs apps using @nx/nest:app NestJsApp1, and middleware libs using @nx/node:lib libs/middleware
This is the Logger Middleware.
@Injectable()
export class LoggingMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        console.log(`LoggingMiddleware: ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
        next();
    }
}


This is my NestJSApp1 => AppModule.ts
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LoggingMiddleware } from 'middlewares';

@Module({
    imports: [],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(LoggingMiddleware)
            .forRoutes('*'); // Apply to all routes
    }
}

When i server my app, it is working fine. LoggerMiddleware is working properly.
However, when I build my app using command nx run app1:build, the app is build without any issue,
when then i try to run the main.js from dist, it is throwing error that Middleware Module cannot be found.
I looked into the appModule in dist. This is the build structure:
dist
    -> apps
        -> app1
            -> src
                -> appModules.js
                -> all other js

    -> lib
        -> middlewares
            -> src 
                -> index.js

Inside appModule, the middleware is being imported:
var import_middlewares = require("middlewares");

However, if i manually change the path to point the middlewares, it is working.
var import_middlewares = require("../../../libs/middlewares/src");

So any reason why the build is not able to point to the lib correctly ?

I stumbled upon a similar issue (by chance) today. I can't even generate using @nx/nest:middleware outside of apps/ folder. For instance libs/server/ returns: The provided directory resolved relative to the current working directory "libs/server" does not exist under any project root. Please make sure to navigate to a location or provide a directory that exists under a project root.
